# Incorrect syntax near in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I spend lot of time to figure out, what is the error,

l have code like this.

```
DECLARE @GeofenceName nvarchar(50) = '';
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = N'select * from GeofenceMaster where GeofenceName = GName'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'GName nvarchar(50)',@GeofenceName

PRINT @sql
```

it throw a error like this.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'GName'.
>   select * from GeofenceMaster where GeofenceName = GName

anybody know which cause this problem?

Comment: What do you expect the parameters `N'GName nvarchar(50)'` and `@GeofenceName` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the variable "GName" (should have @, in this case would @GName), try with the following code, this works perfectly (for more info, see this [LINK](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499)):

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @GName AS nvarchar(50) = ''

SET @sql = N'select * from GeofenceMaster where GeofenceName = ''' + @GName + ''''

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@GName nvarchar(50)',GName

PRINT @sql
```

Comment: is the `@` is must, where i can the documentation.

Comment: Hi BalaKrishnan웃, not understood well your question, but if you need documentation please go here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499 On this page there are two examples that work perfectly, please copy-paste and help you understand the method "sp_executesql"

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**:

The original answer is incorrect. No parentheses should be required. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.105).aspx

**New answer**

Try

```
DECLARE @GeofenceName nvarchar(50) = '';

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @sql = N'select * from GeofenceMaster where GeofenceName = @GName'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'GName nvarchar(50)',@GName=@GeofenceName
```

I've amended the SQL itself, `... = GName` becomes `... = @GName` and the execution, `..., @GeofenceName` becomes `..., @GName = @GeofenceName`.

**Original answer**

You need to add some brackets.

Instead of

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'GName nvarchar(50)',@GeofenceName
```

Try

```
EXEC sp_executesql(@sql,N'GName nvarchar(50)',@GeofenceName)
```

Comment: Well, the official name would be paratheses, but yes, the characters `(` and `)` must be used to delimit parameters to a stored procedure.